# WebForms vs MVC3

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms

Please, I need your help

I'm going to start a new Pure Ajax Web Developement.

I have been investigating WebForms and MVC3 and I'm not very sure which fits better for our project.

I know that in teams with no experience in MVC3 , the learning curve is important, but in this case It won't be an important cons for us.

I don't know if the luck of the ViewState is an important thing or not, why Microsoft has delete it in MVC?.

The luck of Server Controls isn't important either for us.

Can anyone said me which model (WebForms, MVC3) is better to use?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like MVC is the better option for you, I'm not sure why you describe the ViewState as lucky, but the majority are very glad that it is no longer used, as it added considerable overhead to the rendered output, and was very unclean.

It can be a very useful mechanism for preserving data between requests, but it is so integrated with WebForms, that it is often hard to work with. MVC provides a far greater separation of concerns than WebForms, which leads to greater code reuse and easier modular replacement, including much greater support for unit testing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You have given me the answer I expected.

I have mentioned ViewState because some people have said to me it was a good thing, hehe.

My Web Developments have always been with an own out of sync Enterprise Framework so I don't know much about Webforms and ViewState.

I have done a MVC3 investigation and I have seen very interesting.

Comment: @devdigital: I think the OP mis-typed "luck"; I think he really meant "lack".